# How to Dismiss a notification in android when there are multiple notification with different notification Ids?

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

How to Dismiss a notification in android when there are multiple notification with different notification Ids and when I cancel notification only one of them is canceled

Using below lines I am able to remove only one notification not all.

```
public class BlankReceiverClass extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public BlankReceiverClass() {
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //nothing to do
        NotificationManager manager= (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
        Intent noDataActivityIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
        context.sendBroadcast(noDataActivityIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use a cycle?

Comment: have you tried
manager.cancelAll();

Comment: When you create Notification with same Notification Id again and again. 
then only last Notification with that ID will be cancelled. 
You can either remove all notifications with cancelAll()
Or you can cancel specific notification with cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID)

Comment: if you want to remove multiple notifications, You have to keep notification id of all notificaions somewhere in a list or any other way you can manage. Then you can remove them one by one with specific Notification Id

Comment: Your problem is still not clear to me. 
What you exactly want to achieve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by simply passing the notification ID in to the PendingIntent like this

```
Intent noActionIntent = new Intent(this, CancelNotificationReceiver.class);
noActionIntent.putExtra("NotificationID", noti_1_ID);
pendingNoActionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, noti_1_ID, noActionIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

and passing value of notification id through intent into the BroadcastReceiver like this code fragment

```
public class CancelNotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        int notificationId = intent.getIntExtra("NotificationID", 0);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.cancel(notificationId);

        context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS));
    }
}
```

Note: **"context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS));"** It is used to close notification drawer after notification is dismissed